# Remote restart TFS 2012 server build service from another PC

Tags: tfs

At the moment I often have to restart the Build Service of TFS 2012 server by remote desktop to this server at hit Restart as below snapshot.

I want a quicker way to restart this remotely. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use PowerShell for this. Just put name of the service and address of your server.

```
$remoteMachineName = "Your machine address"
$serviceName = "Your Service Name"

Restart-Service -InputObject $(Get-Service -Computer $remoteMachineName -Name $serviceName);
```